# how to use gzsdf?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello i want to transform an URDF file into a SDF file. (I am using Ros fuerte)

What am I doing wrong?

john@john-K53SD:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo$ ./gazebo/bin/gzsdf print /home/john/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/miurdf/01-myfirstyo.urdf

Warning [parser.cc:348] Gazebo SDF has no gazebo element
Error [parser.cc:263] parse as old deprecated model file failed.
Error: SDF parsing the xml failed

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1159/how-to-use-gzsdf-?/) by [Jey_316](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/165/jey_316/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 55 on 2013-01-31

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The command should be *$./gazebo/bin/gzsdf convert your.urdf*

And if you get another error, try sourcing the bash file: *$source setup.bash* from gazebo

!!!! EDIT: 
I remember on older Gazebo (~1.0) versions I used to do it like this:

source setup.bash, **~/path/gazebo$ source setup.bash**

**rosrun gazebo urdf2model -f yourmodel.urdf -o oldgazeboformat.xml** (changes the urdf to gazebo model)

then

**gzsdf print oldgazeboformat.xml > yourmodel.sdf** (from gazebo model to sdf)

Hope it works.

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2013-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jey_316](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/165/jey_316/) on 2013-02-01**:
it didnt work  @AndreiHaidu

john@john-K53SD:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo$  source setup.bash

john@john-K53SD:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo$ ./gazebo/bin/gzsdf convert /home/john/ros/01-myfirstyo.urdf

Error: Unknown option[convert]

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2013-02-01**:
Hi, I updated the answer, see if it works that way, Cheers.

**Comment by [Bharadwaj Ramesh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/154/bharadwaj-ramesh/) on 2013-04-02**:
Hi, I am trying to convert my urdf to sdf format. I tried the your edited commands. THe rosrun command did generate a xml file. But the gzsdf does not work. It says missing robot element in the xml file .